# Sampling volumes of the spectrahedron

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, volume, geometric-probability, convex-hulls

Consider the following set (spectrahedron/spectraheplex)

$$\mathcal A = \left\{ W : W \succeq 0, \mbox{tr}(W)=1 \right\}$$

Consider an approximating set

$$\mathcal B = \mbox{co} \left\{ u_i u_i^T : \|u_i\|_2 = 1, i=1,\dots,k \right\}$$

the convex hull of a set of points where $u_i$ are uniformly sampled on the unit sphere.

I want to compute

$$\frac{\mathbb E[ \mbox{vol}(\mathcal B)] }{ \mbox{vol}(\mathcal A) }$$

as a function of $k$. Any ideas as to possible approaches, related literature, or related problems?

I’m completely stuck, though I feel it must be related to the expected volume of a randomly inscribed polygon in a circle, which I can compute.

Comment: $\mathcal A$ is called **spectraplex** (a portmanteau derived from "spectrahedron" and "simplex", I assume).

Comment: From [Semidefinite Optimization and Convex Algebraic Geometry](https://books.google.com/books?id=O7hxRDy9vrIC), a [paragraph on the spectraplex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8mDr.png) [PNG].

Comment: ah, cool! i actually have that book, i’ll scour it a bit more!

Comment: You might be better off replacing the singleton tag [tag:spectahedra] by [tag:geometric-probability], since it looks like techniques used in answers under that tag might be applicable here.